# django-markupfield returns string

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm trying to set up a Django app that has a [MarkupField](https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield) in it's model, like this:

```
from django.db import models
from markupfield.fields import MarkupField

class Recipe(models.Model):
    instructions = MarkupField(default_markup_type='markdown')
```

Then I render the field in a Jinja2 template, like this:

```
{% if recipe.instructions %}
    {{ recipe.instructions }}
{% else %}
    No instructions have been added yet.
{% endif %}
```

Rendering of the markdowned text works flawless, but it is placed as a string inside the DOM so the browser doesn't interpret the HTML tags, like you can see here:

[image: View in the browser, note the <p> tag.]

[image: View in the DOM inspector, also note the <p> tags.]

I don't feel like I missed something relevant in the django-markupfield's docs, but somehow I need to get rid of this string representation.

Anyone of you guys got an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add the `safe` filter does it works: `{{ recipe.instructions|safe }}`?

Comment: @doru Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: If you use `recipe.instructions.rendered` does it make any change?

Comment: @doru Doesn't work either. I managed to get it working by `{% autoescape off %}{{ recipe.instructions }}{% endautoescape %}` like suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029280/how-to-render-django-template-variable-as-html). Find it to be a bit inconvenient though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @doru's advices I stumbled across the Jinja2 documentation and found the autoescaping statement:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ recipe.instructions }}{% endautoescape %}
```

This one worked for me.

It's even possible to make it work globally by setting the `autoescape` option to `False`.

```
{
    'BACKEND': 'django_jinja.backend.Jinja2',
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'autoescape': False,
        ...
    }
},
```